# MYSQL Hebrew Date in DB

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am looking for a way to handle Hebrew dates for a client. Is it possible to take a Hebrew date and store it in a MYSQL database as a Date and not as a string so that it can be evaluated against?

Something like:
1) fetch row from DB
2) if today is the same as the DB Hebrew date, do something.

OR

1) Fetch all rows where Hebrew date equals today's Hebrew date.

Is that possible without relying on string comparison?

Comment: You could write a function to convert date -> string and vice-versa. Then you can store as a string but run comparisons on the converted date

Comment: This may be of assistance http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49151/hebrew-calender-api-library-in-php-or-javascript-to-add-days-month-or-years-to

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks!

Comment: If you come up with an answer, please consider posting it (as an answer) here for the benefit of the SO community.

Comment: if it can help, there are been topics about that also on [MYSQL forums](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,6544,6544#msg-6544)